# Uniform Continuity picture

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

On the wikipedia page, there is a picture and there is this statement:

The graph of f(x)=1/x escapes the top and/or bottom of the height x width= 2ε x 2δ window, however small the δ, so f(x) is not uniformly continuous. The function g(x)= sqrt (x) on the other hand is uniformly continuous.

I have two questions: 
1. What does it mean to escape the top and// or bottom of the window?
2. Why is 2ε x 2δ  used here when the defintion of uniform continuity only talks about ε and δ?

Also sorry if you have to click the the image to the wikipedia page, but I have inserted it in this page if you can't see it. And pardon my English as I am trying to work on my English, Dutch is my first language.. thanks

[image]

Comment: Notice that the blue graph intersects the black bar on the bottom of the blue rectangle. That is what they mean by "escapes the top and/or bottom". Also, the statement $|x-x_0| < \delta$ means $x \in (x_0 -\delta, x_0 + \delta)$, which is an interval with length $2\delta$ (which is what the width of the square represents).

Answer (score 1):

I think this sort of question can only be answered by 'experience', so I've recreated the graphic in Desmos for you to explore - keep in mind the definition of continuity and uniform continuity: what would "$|x-x_0|<\delta, |f(x) - f(x_0)|<\epsilon$" look like? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fpiuubrk2u

[image]